# How to search an html document as if it were plaintext in python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

so I'm trying to make a program that spiders a website and searches every page for certain snippets of code which are stored in a large file.

To do this, I need to pull the html source from the page and then create an html object -- I am using BeautifulSoup to do this. Initially I tried using this function to actually match the code to the html source

```
def textsearch(soup, exploit): 
    code = soup.find(text = re.compile(exploit)) 
    if code == None:
        print "Coudln't find the bad stuff!\n"
        return False
    else: 
        print "Found the bad code!\n" 
        return True
```

After reading through BS4's documentation I realized this won't work, so I started working on a parser to take in the "exploit" and parse it out into  and text. Problem is not all the exploits have that format(some are javascript scripts), so it'd be better of I could treat the entire html source as one big "text document" with the exact characters that show up in the source, but no formatting, and then just search for any matching sequence of characters.

Is there a good module for turning an html source fetched from the web into such an object?

Answer (score -1):

i think this will help

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 0
    while page <=max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.indeed.co.in/jobs?q=tripura&start=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for jobs in soup.findAll('h2',{'class' :'jobtitle'}):
            #job = jobs.findAll('h2',{'class' :'jobtitle'})
            href = "http://www.indeed.co.in/" + jobs.a.get('href')
            title= jobs.a.string
            print(title)
            print(href)
            page +=10

trade_spider(20)
```